# Passing a JSON object to a function on server side, I get only [object Object]

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm trying to create a JSON object on client-side and pass to a server-side function. Then instantiate it on server-side using JSON string representation.

So I create jSON object on client-side

```
 var myJsonObject = {
        "arg1": var1,
        "arg2": var2
    }
```

and pass it in to

```
    WebForm_DoCallback(controlID, myJsonObject , null, null, null, true);
```

When I try to retrieve this JSON object on server-size I get as a string representation of JSON `[object Object]`

So in following server-side function, the argument value is `[object Object]`

```
public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string jsonObj)
```

I was expecting a string representation of JSON object. How do I pass in a string representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be serialized (stringified). Try this: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js.